# Render WKT data from HTTP calls, or JDBC

Tags: maps, http, gis, jdbc

I have a proprietary database, which I can access either through JDBC, or HTTP calls.
The database has WKT data
I want a desktop viewer that works on Linux to show the data,
and preferably it is free.